# How to convert List in database to List in viewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel called applicantVm and I am trying to display a list of family's children that are currently registered. I use a stored procedure to return the list but am having difficulty with converting the results to the ViewModel and displaying it.

**In my ViewModel:**

```
[Display(Name = "Child First Name")]
[Required]
public string  ChildFirstName { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Child's Date Of Birth")]
public DateTime ChildDateOfBirth { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Grade { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Grade Entering")]
[Required]
public int SelectedGradeId { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Grades { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<StudentVm> Students { get; set; }
```

in my controller

```
public ActionResult Application()
{
    var currentUserEmail = User.Identity.Name;
    var familyMembers = _db.sp_ApplicantFamily_SelectFamilyMembers(User.Identity.Name).ToList();

    List<ApplicantVm> applicantVmList = new List<ApplicantVm>();
    ApplicantVm applicantVm = new ApplicantVm();
    foreach (var child in familyMembers)
    {
        //Here is where I get an error
        foreach ( var student in applicantVm.Students)
        {
            student.FirstName = child.FirstName;                    
        }              
    }

    return View();
}
```

I get an error at applicantvm.student:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How do I set all the Children's properties to student properties?

Comment: You cant iterate over a null object.  Your object is null because the List was never initialized

Comment: For fun, Google the actual error message and see what kind of help comes up

Comment: I understand the error. The question is how to resolve it.

Comment: If  you understand the error and got the @maccettura tip, you can resolve the issue

Comment: @Curious-programmer I dont think you understand the error, because if you did you would already know how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ViewModel, you should do something like this; at very least.
What you're missing is you haven't initialize the Student list, at any place of code.

```
private List<string> _goodList = new List<string>();
public List<string> GoodOnes
{   
    get
    { return _goodList;}
    set
    {
        _goodList = value;
    }
}
```

This is a very basic example and you should be able to apply this to yours.

Comment: Why have a private backing field?   Why not initialize in the constructor or have a default initializer in the auto property?

Comment: @maccettura I know it's old school. just wanted give a bit theoretical example.